# python queue when exception occurs before task_done

Tags: python, queue

Scenario:

```
# readQ is a queue
# threaded_func is used via python threading
def threaded_func(readQ): 
    while True:
    taskval=readQ.get()

    # some unknown error happens here throwing some exception
    # this causes thread to exit at this point
    # this also means readQ.task_done below is never called for that readQ.get
    readQ.task_done()
```

So, if the queue item was read but task_done is not invoked and the thread has died,
is there a way to check:

1. items in the queue that have been 'checked out' but not complete
2. How long have they been 'checked out' without a task_done?
3. Can I pull the plug on such tasks and put it back in the 'available' mode?